# How to display backgroung image once it's assigned as constant using styled components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I want to display background image on full size of the parent component, this image is assigned to const "image", parent is Dialog from Material UI. Below is the code which I have now and not working. How should I implement it ?

```
const image =
        '../../../../../../shared/src/lib/assets/images/logo/SVG/nevomo_logo_orange.svg';
    return (
        <div>
            <StyledLogo onClick={handleClickOpen} />
            <StyledDialog
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="alert-picture-zoom-in"
                open={open}
                sx={{ backgroundImage: { image } }}
            >
                <StyledImageContent>sss</StyledImageContent>
                <StyledCloseIcon onClick={handleClose} />
            </StyledDialog>

export const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)`
    & .MuiDialog-paper {
        overflow: unset;
        height: 50rem;
        width: 46.4rem;
        border: 0.4rem solid #ffffff;
        border-radius: unset;
        background-image: ${(props) => props.image};
    }
`;
```

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import img from 'your path to image';

export const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)`
    background-image: url(${img});
    width: 100%;

    & .MuiDialog-paper {
        overflow: unset;
        height: 50rem;
        width: 46.4rem;
        border: 0.4rem solid #fff;
        border-radius: unset;
        background-image: ${(props) => props.image};
    }
`;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for advise. I wanted to have this picture as const because soon const image will be data passed from Context, so it will be dynamic. For the moment I wanted to make the code working in that scheme that image is saved under const, and later on just change minor things to make it work with data fetched from context